# why datatype has to be 'uint8' in Opencv python wrapper?

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to create an image of **gray** color using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cv=cv2

s=np.zeros((240, 320, 3), dtype=int)
s[s==0]=128
cv.imshow('3', s)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I get a totally **black** image. When I write the image to a file, it **indeed** is a gray image:

```
fn='example.jpg'
cv.imwrite(fn, s)
```

So I have to change `int` to `uint8`, then everything works well. But I'm still curious that why I have to use `uint8` instead of `int`, is there any docs describing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow), OpenCV changes its behavior according to the type of the array:

> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

Hence, the following will all produce the same image grayscale image:

```
s = np.zeros((240, 320), dtype=np.uint8)
s[s==0] = 128
```

`int32`:

```
s = np.zeros((240, 320), dtype=np.int32)
s[s==0] = 128 * 256
```

`float32`:

```
s = np.zeros((240, 320), dtype=np.float32)
s[s==0] = 128 / 256.0
```

Comment: great! thx man! Then now the question is: why `cv.imshow` is inconsistent with `cv.imwrite`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen That's up to the authors of OpenCV. The question of why an API is designed a certain way has no definitive answer; we can only speculate.

Answer (score 4):

`uint8` is an unsigned 8-bit integer that can represent values 0..255. `int` on the other hand is usually a 32-bit signed integer. When you create array using dtype=int, each element in that aray takes 4 bytes. OpenCV apparently expect array to be made of 8-bit tuples representing red, green and blue. So when you pass array of integers, the memory will contain something like this:

> 0x00000080 0x00000080 0x00000080.......

Which openCV interprets as:

> {R=0x00,G=0x00,B=0x00} {R=0x80,G=0x00,B=0x00}, {R=0x00, G=0x00, B=0x00}...

My guess is what you've got very dark image which, on closer inspection would show very dim red, green and blue pixels.

When you changed type to uint8, your array would look like this:

> 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80....

Which is then interpreted by OpenCV as gray RGB values:

> {R=0x80,G=0x80,B=0x80}

Answer (score 4):

Because the default dtype that OpenCV reads the image in is 'uint8' so everything which operates on that image has to be of 'uint8' type for compatibility

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gray image as output then must try this below code to to get an expecting result. Well nice try.

> ```
> import cv2 as cv 
> import numpy as np
>
> img = cv.imread('C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Opencv/tiger.png')
> #cv.imshow('tiger', img)  #this code will shows you a normal image
> #cv.waitKey(0)  
> #cv.destroyAllWindows()
> gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
> cv.imshow('Gray', gray)
> #this above code will shows you a gray colour image
> cv.waitKey(0)
> cv.destroyAllWindows()
> ```

If you want more info please read the colour conversion documentation - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html